# Remove Watermark of Aero Glass on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, aero, watermark

Recently I have installed [Aero Glass for windows 8.1](https://www.glass8.eu/download) and noticed that it creates a watermark of the site name and this is how it looks:

[image: this is how it looks]

Also at the startup of windows a window pops up saying "You are using the free version of Aero glass". Is there work around to purge these issues.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there work around to purge these issues?

From their support forum:

> the pinned FAQ specifically states that the only way to remove the watermark is to donate.

Source [Does anyone know a way to remove the popup and watermark without donating? - Aero Glass For Windows 8+ - MSFN](https://msfn.org/board/topic/182917-does-anyone-know-a-way-to-remove-the-popup-and-watermark-without-donating/)

So you need to make a donation to remove the watermark.

Comment: There is no answer on the forum.

Comment: "you need to make a donation to remove the watermark."

Comment: Is there no other work around to solve these issues